# Background colour doesn't change on all triggers

Tags: jquery, background-color

I want a fixed element to change its background colour depending on which section the user scrolls past. The code I have works on one section, but not others. As a test, I configured it to also change the background colour of the sections themselves, and it works.

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    $(".section").each(function () {
        var box = $("#box");
        var BoxTop = box.position().top;
        var BoxBottom = BoxTop + box.outerHeight();
        var section = $(this);
        var sectionTop = section.position().top - $(window).scrollTop() + 15;
        var sectionBottom = section.position().top - $(window).scrollTop() + section.height();
        if ((sectionTop >= BoxTop && sectionTop <= BoxBottom) || (sectionTop <= BoxTop && sectionBottom >= BoxBottom) || (sectionBottom >= BoxTop && sectionBottom <= BoxBottom)) {
            section.css("background", "blue");
            box.css("background", "blue");
        } else {
            section.css("background", "red");
            box.css("background", "red");
        }
    });

});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xo1Lyfnc/1/

Comment: You should not do calculation with section.position().top but rather use the intersectionObserver in JS which does these calculations for yourself. Then you define which element should be visible for how much percent or intersecting with another element for any given percentage and then you react to that.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API

Comment: @cloned Thank you. I'm looking into that right now. Do you know what causes the sections' background colour to change in my current code but not the fixed element's? I don't know what I'm missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you are experiencing is because you are looping over all the sections, and are changing the background accordingly.

Because you are not breaking out of the loop (when you match the section) the result will be overridden in the next iteration of the loop. This means, that the desired functionality will only work for the last `.section` on the page.

To make it work for all your sections, simple break the loop after you match a section. In jQuery's `each` function you can do this by returning `false`.

Your updated code:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    $(".section").each(function () {
        var box = $("#box");
        var BoxTop = box.position().top;
        var BoxBottom = BoxTop + box.outerHeight();
        var section = $(this);
        var sectionTop = section.position().top - $(window).scrollTop() + 15;
        var sectionBottom = section.position().top - $(window).scrollTop() + section.height();
        if ((sectionTop >= BoxTop && sectionTop <= BoxBottom) || (sectionTop <= BoxTop && sectionBottom >= BoxBottom) || (sectionBottom >= BoxTop && sectionBottom <= BoxBottom)) {
            section.css("background", "blue");
            box.css("background", "blue");
            return false; // We found a match, so stop trying to match the other sections.
        } else {
            section.css("background", "red");
            box.css("background", "red");
        }
    });

});
```

[A working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0uoLtn53/)